# Função que recarrega a pagina após outra função

Tags: javascript

Bom eu tenho um select que executa uma função onclick quando seleciona um opção do select, ele retorna para uma função chamada gotoRefresh, que executa um select no banco de dados para trazer dados no grid de acordo com o que foi selecionado no select.

O problema é, toda vez que executa isso, ele faz tudo corretamente, só que ele não recarrega a pagina... então só vai mostrar as alterações se eu der um F5... como posso alterar para recarregar automaticamente ?

Meu select:

```
<select name='FAZ1' id='FAZ1' type='text' style="display:inline"
lang='Faz1,N'
onchange='Javascript:return gotoRefreshOrderBy();'>

    <struts_logic:iterate id="arrhh_empresa" name="collhh_empresa" scope="page" type="java.util.ArrayList">
            <option value='<%=arrhh_empresa.get(0).toString()%>'
                                    <%=arrhh_empresa.get(0).toString().equals(strEmpresaUserSelecionada) ? "selected" : ""%> >
                                    <%=arrhh_empresa.get(1).toString()%>
            </option>
    </struts_logic:iterate>

</select>
```

Minha função gotoRefresh:

```
function gotoRefreshOrderBy(){
    document.FrmTelaBranca.action='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/list_webcbvcadastros.do';
    goList();
}
```

Imagem com o menu e também da url que insere esse eventName quando faz a função, alguém sabe porque ele insere esse eventName na URL ? não gostaria que aparecesse também

[image: Botão que da a função onclick e o evento que adiciona na url quando executa a função]

Answer (score -1):

```
function goList(){

        document.FrmTelaBranca.submit();
        window.setTimeout(function () {
        // Redireciona para a pagina
        location.href = "list_wmsbdotpequipamentos.do";
    }, 5000);
    }
```

fiz assim, se eu tirar o document.FrmTelaBranca, ele redireciona apos 5 segundos para o pagina, mas eu preciso do submit para ele dar o eventName, mas se eu deixar o document ele não faz nada